# Как в массиве оставить только один ObjectId (MongoDB)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

в коллекции posts храню все идентификаторы пользователей который лайкнули запись, мне нужно при получении данных с сервера проверить существует ли текущий ID пользователя в posts.likes.

Я пробовал сделать это с помощью $filter, но не получилось

Вот структура документа

```
{
 _id: 'id_post'
 {
   likes: [
      ObjectId('id_user1'),
      ObjectId('id_user2'),
      ObjectId('id_user3'),
      ObjectId('id_user4'),
      ObjectId('id_user5')
   ]
 }
}
```

Если ID пользователя равен id_user**4**, мне нужно получить такой объект

```
{
 _id: 'id_post'
 {
   likes: [
      ObjectId('id_user4')
   ]
 }
}
```

Попытки

```
Posts.aggregate([
   { $limit: 1 },
   {
     $project: {
        _id: 1,
        likes: {
           $filter: {
              input: '$likes',
              as: 'likes',
              cond: { _id: sessionID }
           }
        }
     }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Posts.find({"likes":{$in:[ObjectId('id_user4')]}}, {_id:1, "likes.$":1})
```

**UPD:**

```
Posts.aggregate(
{ $unwind: { path: "$likes",  "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},
{
   $project: {
       "_id":1,
       "likes": { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$likes", ObjectId('id_user4')] }, then: "$likes", else: null } }    
    }
},
{
    $group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        likes:{$first:'$likes'}
    }
})
```

Comment: Это не то что нужно, такой запрос выведет только те записи где есть _id, мне нужно в потоке чекать присутствует ли likes._id или нет, если он присутствует то оставить его в поле likes, если его нет, то поле likes нужно оставить пустым (null или [])  Все это для того чтобы в реальном времени проверять статус кнопки likes у каждой записи. Сейчас я это делаю с помощью костыля. Когда в цикле при формировании html кода делаю такую проверку const classLike = (JSON.stringify(x.likes||[]).search(user && user._id || 'guest') < 0 && 'like_white' || 'like_red')

Comment: @webphp возможен такой вариант....

Comment: Это работает, но с unwind это как то дерзко)) я думаю при большом объеме поля likes будут жесткие нагрузки) Пока лучше костылем попользуюсь, может в будущем монго придумает что нибудь похожее на мой костыль ) А за решение спасибо, но если будут другие варианты с радостью приму)